# Como puedo buscar un Dato en un DatagridView sin base de datos

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Hola muy buena a todos mi pregunta es como puedo buscar un dato en un datagridview mediante un textbox, a lo que me refiero es teclear y si coincide lo que teclee en el texbox aparezca en el datagridview sin una base de datos.

Comment: Mira [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: debes colocar algo de código, para que se pueda ayudar en tu pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Usando **RowFilter**, deberías agregar el evento

```
 TextChanged
```

Al textbox con el que deseas filtrar y dentro, vas seteando cual es la condición, por ejemplo

```
 (dataGridViewFields.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Nombre = '{0}'", textBoxBusqueda.Text);
```

En este caso cuando escribas el ''Nombre'' en el textbox, el DataGridView solo va a mostrar la fila correspondiente a ese nombre.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por comentar me salta un error al escribir en el textbox me arroja el error 'No se controlo NullReferenceException' a que se debera el problema.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agregá el código donde creas la tabla, y el evento `TextChanged` así puedo verlo e intento ayudarte mejor